# Problemas con php sql Notice: Undefined variable: con in sis-trabajo \conexion\configServer.php on line 18

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema quiero realizar la siguiente consulta en mi página:
`UPDATE estudiante est JOIN trabajo trab ON trab.titulo = 'seguimiento de trabajo de grado' and est.ID_estudiante = 7 SET est.trabajo = trab.ID_trabajo;`

Pero por alguna razón me salta error. Trate de adaptarlo a otra estructura pero me sigue fallando este es mi código la linea 18 es el `die` de la función consultar:

```
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function conectar(){
        if(!$con=  mysqli_connect(SERVER,USER,PASS)){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }
        if (!mysqli_select_db($con,BD)) {
            die("Error al conectar con la base de datos, verifique el nombre de la base de datos");
        }
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
        return $con;  
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if (!$consul = mysqli_query(ejecutarSQL::conectar(),$query)) {
            die(mysqli_error($con).'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }  
}
class consultasSQL{
    public static function InsertSQL($tabla, $campos, $valores) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("insert into $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function DeleteSQL($tabla, $condicion) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("delete from $tabla where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al eliminar los registros en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function UpdateSQL($tabla, $campos, $condicion) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("update $tabla set $campos where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function UpdJoinTrSQL($tabla1, $tabla2, $condicion, $campos) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("update $tabla1 join $tabla2 on $condicion set $campos")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla1");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
```

Y en esta el que falla solo en el cuarto if los otros funcionan con normalidad en la funcion UpdJoinTrSQL:

```
if(!$titulo=="" && !$descripcion=="" && !$area=="" && !$tipo=="" && !$idestt==""){
    $verificar=  ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from trabajo where titulo='".$titulo."'");
    $verificaltotal = mysqli_num_rows($verificar);
    
    if($verificaltotal<=0){
        // en vez de usuario pones estudiante
        if(consultasSQL::InsertSQL("trabajo", "titulo, descripcion, area_desempeno, tipo", "'$titulo','$descripcion','$area','$tipo'")){
               
            if(consultasSQL::UpdJoinTrSQL("estudiante", "trabajo", "trabajo.titulo='$titulo' and estudiante.ID_estudiante='$idestt'", "est.trabajo=trab.ID_trabajo")){
            echo '
                <script>
                  var r = confirm("Se asigno con exito");
                  if (r == true) {
                    location.href="../admin/seg_trab.php";
                  } else {
                    location.href="../admin/seg_trab.php";
                  }
                
                </script>
            ';
            }
        }
}
}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\sis-trabajo\conexion\configServer.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sis-trabajo\conexion\configServer.php on line 18
```

Error en la consulta `SQL` ejecutada.

Comment: El error Undefined variable es porque no acabas de hacer la conexión a la base de datos, o no aparece en el código que has enviado. Se puede ver que haces una function con la conexión, y pones mysqli_connect(SERVER,USER,PASS), tienes que declarar SERVER, USER,PASS.

Comment: si lo hice es mas todas las otras funcionan normalmente solo me fallla esta consulta '<?php
define("USER", "root");
define("SERVER", "localhost");
define("BD", "sist-trabajo");
define("PASS", "");

?>

Answer (score 0):

creo que su error viene al tener la conexión de la base de datos en una `function`, sugiriendo lo que yo hago en los `UPDATE` pondría la conexión fuera y al principio de la página `php`.
De tal manera que quedaría así:

```html
<?php
$hostdb = "introduzca aquí lo que tenga";     // localhost or IP
$userdb = "lo mismo aquí";         // database username
$passdb = "su contraseña";            // database password
$namedb = "su tabla";    // database name

$con = mysqli_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

if($con->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed ".$con->connect_error);



class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if (!$consul = mysqli_query(ejecutarSQL::conectar(),$query)) {
            die(mysqli_error($con).'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }  
}
class consultasSQL{
    public static function InsertSQL($tabla, $campos, $valores) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("insert into $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function DeleteSQL($tabla, $condicion) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("delete from $tabla where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al eliminar los registros en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function UpdateSQL($tabla, $campos, $condicion) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("update $tabla set $campos where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
    public static function UpdJoinTrSQL($tabla1, $tabla2, $condicion, $campos) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("update $tabla1 join $tabla2 on $condicion set $campos")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla1");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
<?
```

Si esto no lo funciona, podría insertar la conexión en la misma función de la consulta.
Espero que esto le sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si le salta algún error, comunícanos-lo en comentarios.

Comment: tengo los dos establecidos en funciones que importo previo a la realizacion `<?php
include '../conexion/consulSQL.php';
include '../conexion/configServer.php';`  y el consul SQL es <?php
define("USER", "root");
define("SERVER", "localhost");
define("BD", "sist-trabajo");
define("PASS", "");

?>`   por eso se me hace un poco extraño que no funcione ya que la funcion de insert update y delete si funcionan con esta estructura